# Mocha: Is there a scenario where a before hook would run after a test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, mocha.js, hook

My before hook is running after the first test, at the end of the second test

the code for my before hook:

```
before(function () {
    insightFacade.addDataset("courses", content)
        .then(function (result: InsightResponse) {
            console.log("then");
        })
        .catch(function (err: InsightResponse) {
            console.log("catch");
        });
});
```

also to be noted is that sometimes the first 2 tests instead of just the first 1 would fail, depending on how i order my tests, but the second test always fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn’t return the promise, so Mocha doesn’t know to wait for it. The `before` hook queues up a task to run asynchronously, and the first test starts in the meantime.

```
before(function () {
    return insightFacade.addDataset("courses", content)
        .then(function (result: InsightResponse) {
            console.log("then");
        })
        .catch(function (err: InsightResponse) {
            console.log("catch");
        });
});
```

Comment: with a return, i get '"before all" hook has failed' in the run window (Webstorm) for every test second one

Comment: @icda: Were any error details logged? Do you still have a `catch` that *only* contains a `console.log`?

Comment: it's the only thing that shows in the run box; i still have a catch that only contains a console.log

Comment: @icda: If you replace the whole thing with a `return Promise.resolve();`, does the error still appear?

Comment: also to be noted is that sometimes the first 2 tests instead of just the first 1 would fail, depending on how i order my tests, but the second test always fails

Comment: when i replace the whole thing with that, the ' "before all" hook failed ' error is no longer there

Comment: @icda: Well, `insightFacade.addDataset` is misbehaving somehow. It might be throwing synchronously. Try `try { return insightFacade.addDataSet(… } catch (error) { console.log("caught", error); }`?

Comment: the " 'before all' hook failed" is back (it replaces the entire run window with that single statement), even though catch did not catch an error; would you say that this discussion should be moved to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134939/discussion-between-ryan-and-icda).